# Help solving $y^{\prime\prime}(1+2\ln(y^\prime)) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p = y^\prime$, then we get $p^\prime(1+2\ln(p))=1$, so $x + c_1 = \int(1+2\ln(p))dp = p(2\ln(p)-1)$.

But then I'm stuck because I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Just a tip that might be worthwhile, before you decide to devote large amounts of time to trying to solve a nonlinear differential equation, you should check if it has a solution in terms of elementary functions. You can easily do that by using wolfram alpha and just scanning the solution quickly for any special functions. This may reduce the benefit of solving it as it gives you a rough idea of what the solution looks like (if it exists), but I think saving time is definitely worth it (especially if you're the tenacious type, you would be stuck looking for something that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do better with the standard functions and you have to use Lambert $W$ function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to now obtain an expression of $p$ as a function of $x$.

More precisely, the function $W$ verifies $w(x)\,e^{w(x)} = x$ (i.e. it is (one of) the inverse function of the function $y\mapsto y\,e^y$), so that $w + \ln w = \ln x$, while your last equation can be written
$$
a = p \ln p - p/2,
$$
where $a= \frac{x+c_1}{2}$, and so
$$
\frac{a}{p} + 1/2 = \ln(p) = -\ln(1/p) = -\ln(a/p) + \ln(a),
$$
from which we get
$$
\tfrac{a}{p} + \ln(\tfrac{a}{p}) = \ln(a/\sqrt{e}).
$$
Therefore, $\frac{a}{p} = w(a/\sqrt{e})$, or equivalently
$$
y'(x) = \frac{x+c_1}{2\,w\!\left(\frac{x+c_1}{2\,\sqrt{e}}\right)}
$$